# Interpolate density using a number of points instead of random sampling

Tags: r, probability-density, kernel-density

When R calculates density(x) it uses n = 512 (I believe) so it randomly tries to pick 512 points and interpolates a density function using those points. I have a list of points (p) that I would like to use when computing density(x) INSTEAD of randomly sampling 512 points. (ignore any complications this may cause, validity, etc. - I am just looking for a way to implement this)

1. Is there a way to modify density(x) so I can pass a list
   of points instead of using random sampling?
2. What is the algorithm that density(x) uses?
3. Is there a different function that I should use for my purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of research, you can calculate kernel density estimate as follows (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)):

```
#` Data
set.seed(1)                                                     #Used for reproducibility
data = c(rnorm(100,-10,1),rnorm(100,10,1))                      #Two Normals mixed

#` True
phi = function(x) exp(-.5*x^2)/sqrt(2*pi)                       #Normal Density
tpdf = function(x) phi(x+10)/2+phi(x-10)/2                      #True Density

#` Kernel
h = sd(data)*(4/3/length(data))^(1/5)                           #Bandwidth estimated by Silverman's Rule of Thumb
Kernel2 = function(x) mean(phi((x-data)/h)/h)                   #Kernel Density
kpdf = function(x) sapply(x,Kernel2)                            #Elementwise application

#` Plot
x=seq(-25,25,length=1000)                                       #Linear Space
plot(x,tpdf(x),type="l",ylim=c(0,0.23),col="red")               #Plot True Density
par(new=T)
plot(x,kpdf(x),type="l",ylim=c(0,0.23),xlab="",ylab="",axes=F)  #Plot Kernel Density with Silverman's Rule of Thumb
```

Notice that I can select `x` in any way I want